# tsch: tab-complete filename after --flag=

Tags: tab-completion, tcsh

One the small annoyances I have in my daily use of tcsh is when I start writing a command like this:

```
# do_stuff --input=/path/to/some
```

I wish to use tab-completion to finish writing `/path/to/some/file`. Is there any way to make tcsh ignore the `--input=` part and allow tab completion here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ complete do_stuff 'c/input=/f/' 'p/*/(--input)/='
```

The first part is to complete filenames after `input=` (`f` flag), the second part is to complete `--input` and append a `=`.

Comment: That is already helpful. Is there any way to do this for the general case?

Comment: @Rodin What do you mean with 'the general case'? By the way, almost all commands allow you to write `do_stuff --input /path/to/some`. You almost never need the `=`.

Comment: By general case, I mean, if I have an additional command `do_other_stuff --foo=/path/to/some`, do I need to write another rule? Or can a rule be written in a general way to cover both cases?

Comment: If I don't need the `=`, this problem would just disappear.... you just made my day :)